# Add permissions group to odoo ir.values register

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a `ir.values` record with the `<field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>` property to appear in the "more" menu.
I need it to be hidden depending on a group of permissions.
I tried to add `<field name="groups">premision_group_name</field>` but it does not work
Is there any way to indicate the permissions for this type of record?

Answer (score 1):

If you make reference to an action in the field value:

```
<field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_sale_order_make_invoice'))" />
```

you can specify the group in the action

```
<act_window id="base.change_password_wizard_action"
            name="Change Password"
            src_model="res.users"
            res_model="change.password.wizard"
            view_type="form" view_mode="form"
            key2="client_action_multi" target="new"
            groups="base.group_administrator"/>
```